# Is it possible to attach an image file to the test case result in Rally using Java rally REST API?

Tags: java, rest, rally

I am trying to attach an image file to the test result in Rally using java Rally REST APIs( A screen shot of the failure). The image file is attaching to the test case itself but not to the test result. Tried to give the testCaseResult reference instead of testCaseReference but getting the error
"Could not set value for Artifact: Cannot use type TestCaseResult in attribute Artifact"
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: The image file will be in a local directory. While executing the automated test case , in the event of failure it takes a screen shot and s saved in a local directory and I am trying to attach this screen shot to my Rally test result.

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example of how to do this. The example creates a new Test Case Result and then adds the Attachment. The trick is to set the attribute of "TestCaseResult" on your Attachment to the _ref of the TestCaseResult of interest. This differs from adding attachments to Stories, for example, where the attribute is "Artifact".

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.DeleteRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.GetRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.UpdateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.DeleteResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.GetResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.UpdateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class RestExample_CreateTestCaseResultAddAttachment {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        // Create and configure a new instance of RallyRestApi
        // Connection parameters
        String rallyURL = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
        String wsapiVersion = "v2.0";
        String applicationName = "RestExample_CreateTestCaseResultAddAttachment";

        // Credentials
        String userName = "user@company.com";
        String userPassword = "topsecret";

        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(rallyURL),
                userName,
                userPassword);
        restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);   

        // Workspace and Project Settings
        String myWorkspace = "/workspace/12345678910";
        String myProject = "/project/12345678911";

        // Test Case to which we want to add a result
        String testCaseFormattedID = "TC40";

        // User name of tester
        String testerRallyID = "tester@testit.com";

        // Reference to created TestCaseResult
        String testCaseResultRef = "";

        // File handle for image to attach
        RandomAccessFile myImageFileHandle;
        String imageFilePath = "/home/username/Pictures/";
        String imageFileName = "image1.jpg";
        String fullImageFile = imageFilePath + imageFileName;
        String imageBase64String;
        long attachmentSize;

        // Open file
        myImageFileHandle = new RandomAccessFile(fullImageFile, "r");        

        //Read User
        QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
        userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "DisplayName"));
        userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", testerRallyID));
        QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
        JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
        JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryResults.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").getAsString();

        // Query for Test Case to which we want to add results
        QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
        testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));
        testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", testCaseFormattedID));
        QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
        JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();        

        // Query for Test Set to which we want to add Test Case
        QueryRequest testSetQuery = new QueryRequest("TestSet");
        testSetQuery.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name","TestCases"));
        testSetQuery.setWorkspace(myWorkspace);
        testSetQuery.setProject(myProject);
        testSetQuery.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TS5"));
        QueryResponse testSetQueryResponse = restApi.query(testSetQuery);
        JsonObject testSetJsonObject = testSetQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        String testSetRef = testSetJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString();
        System.out.println("Test Set Ref: " + testSetRef);

        try {           

            //Add a Test Case Result                
            System.out.println("Creating Test Case Result...");
            JsonObject newTestCaseResult = new JsonObject();
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Inconclusive");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Date", "2013-09-04T18:00:00.000Z");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Automated Selenium Test Runs");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "2013.09.04.0020101");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Tester", userRef);
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", testCaseRef);
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestSet", testSetRef);

            CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcaseresult", newTestCaseResult);
            CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);            

            if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {

                System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));          

                //Read Test Case Result
                testCaseResultRef = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                System.out.println(String.format("\nReading Test Case Result %s...", testCaseResultRef));
                GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(testCaseResultRef);
                getRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Date", "Verdict"));
                GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
                JsonObject obj = getResponse.getObject();
                System.out.println(String.format("Read Test Case Result. Date = %s, Verdict = %s",
                        obj.get("Date").getAsString(), obj.get("Verdict").getAsString()));

                try {
                    // Get and check length
                    long longLength = myImageFileHandle.length();
                    long maxLength = 5000000;
                    if (longLength >= maxLength) throw new IOException("File size >= 5 MB Upper limit for Rally.");
                    int fileLength = (int) longLength;            

                    // Read file and return data
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileLength];
                    myImageFileHandle.readFully(fileBytes);
                    imageBase64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(fileBytes);
                    attachmentSize = fileLength;

                    // First create AttachmentContent from image string
                    JsonObject myAttachmentContent = new JsonObject();
                    myAttachmentContent.addProperty("Content", imageBase64String);
                    CreateRequest attachmentContentCreateRequest = new CreateRequest("AttachmentContent", myAttachmentContent);
                    CreateResponse attachmentContentResponse = restApi.create(attachmentContentCreateRequest);
                    String myAttachmentContentRef = attachmentContentResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
                    System.out.println("Attachment Content created: " + myAttachmentContentRef);            

                    // Now create the Attachment itself
                    JsonObject myAttachment = new JsonObject();
                    myAttachment.addProperty("TestCaseResult", testCaseResultRef);
                    myAttachment.addProperty("Content", myAttachmentContentRef);
                    myAttachment.addProperty("Name", "AttachmentFromREST.jpg");
                    myAttachment.addProperty("Description", "Attachment From REST");
                    myAttachment.addProperty("ContentType","image/jpg");
                    myAttachment.addProperty("Size", attachmentSize);
                    myAttachment.addProperty("User", userRef);          

                    CreateRequest attachmentCreateRequest = new CreateRequest("Attachment", myAttachment);
                    CreateResponse attachmentResponse = restApi.create(attachmentCreateRequest);
                    String myAttachmentRef = attachmentResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
                    System.out.println("Attachment  created: " + myAttachmentRef);  

                    if (attachmentResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                        System.out.println("Successfully created Attachment");
                    } else {
                        String[] attachmentContentErrors;
                        attachmentContentErrors = attachmentResponse.getErrors();
                        System.out.println("Error occurred creating Attachment: ");
                        for (int i=0; i<attachmentContentErrors.length;i++) {
                            System.out.println(attachmentContentErrors[i]);
                        }                   
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception occurred while attempting to create Content and/or Attachment: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();            
                }                           

            } else {
                String[] createErrors;
                createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case Result: ");
                for (int j=0; j<createErrors.length;j++) {
                    System.out.println(createErrors[j]);
                }
            }                        

        } finally {
            //Release all resources
            restApi.close();
            myImageFileHandle.close();            
        }        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It worked. I was doing the very same mistake you mentioned- gave  'Artifact'instead of 'TestCaseResult' :(

Comment: The ref problem is because you're doing jsonObject.get("_ref").toString(), which returns an extra set of wrapping quotes.  Use jsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString() and you should be all set.  We still don't know why this is different between 1.x and v2.x.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, mystery solved! I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Attachment.Size is read-only field hence setting the same is not relevant - https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/