# How to attach a zip file to test case results in rally using rally REST API?

Tags: java, rally

How to attach a zip file to test case results in rally using rally REST API?

I am able to attach an Image file to test case result.

I used the answer provided by StackOverflow in this link: "[Is it possible to attach an image file to the test case result in Rally using Java rally REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703613/is-it-possible-to-attach-an-image-file-to-the-test-case-result-in-rally-using-ja)"

Please help me with attaching zip file also.

Comment: Hi Vishu, welcome to SO. Please tell us what you have tried so far and the problems you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this example to get you started?

https://github.com/RallyCommunity/rally-java-rest-apps/blob/master/CreateDefectAddZipAttachment.java